# Convert system dynamic disk w/o data-loss windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, dynamic, convert

Does anybody know how to convert dynamic system disk to basic in Windows server 2003 without data-loss and if possible without using third-party tools? Is that possible?

I was thinking of making a mirror copy of this disk onto Basic disk and then simply exchanging these disks and changing boot.ini.

Oh, this is virtual server on VMware.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success with this in the past as outlined in the following post:

http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=191006

I would test it out on a test drive first just in case.